# Storing/Query Java Numbers In MongoDB with Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a Java object that has a numeric data field, in some cases it can be a double, int or long and I am using java.lang.Number as the field type which works fine for serialization via JSON.

When inserting into Mongo I am creating a document, and for the field I look to see what its sub class is, if its a double i then use setDouble() etc. This works fine.

The challenge I have is how do I convert the Document back to the POJO object when reading data from the Database. It seems like I have to call getDouble() or getInt() and what I need to know is how do I figure out at query time what the data type is of the field so I can set it correctly. I don't see a way to getNumber() or anything so I'm stuck on figuring it out. Maybe getObject() and then check its class type, I don't know if that is possible or performant. This is for several million documents of data and trying to find the right solution. I could add a field that is an int that tells the data type but trying to avoid that.